# Why using Duration.ZERO in keyframe not changing the YProperty of the node in JavaFX?

Tags: animation, javafx, properties, timeline, keyframe

I am trying to animate a Label using JavaFX Timeline. I need to translate the label from outside the stage to inside. So, I am first setting the translateYProperty of the label to negative value(outside the stage) using Duration.ZERO. According to what I've learned so far it should set the value of YProperty to specified value immediately but when I print it, it shows zero. But when I use any other Duration greater that 0, it gives answer correctly. Please can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?
Here's the code:

```
    Timeline tl = new Timeline();
    KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(registerLabel.translateYProperty(), -150);
    KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, kv);
    tl.getKeyFrames().addAll(kf);
    tl.setOnFinished(e->System.out.println(registerLabel.translateYProperty().get()));
    tl.play();
```

This outputs 0.0 instead of -150.0.

Note: This snippet is not doing the complete animation. I've shown only concerned part of the code.

Whereas, this code gives correct answer:

```
    Timeline tl = new Timeline();
    KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(registerLabel.translateYProperty(), -150);
    KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1), kv);
    tl.getKeyFrames().addAll(kf);
    tl.setOnFinished(e->System.out.println(registerLabel.translateYProperty().get()));
    tl.play();
```

Outputs -150.0.

Comment: My guess is that having a duration of zero means it thinks it's done animating before it actually tries to animate anything. Perhaps that's a bug. In any case, you should be able to fix your problem with `new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, e -> registerLabel.setTranslateY(-150))`. That uses an "on-finished handler" (instead of a `KeyValue`) which will execute when the `KeyFrame` is finished; since the duration is zero it will be finished immediately.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: @Slaw Thanks for your suggestion. I tried that but the output is still the same. I guess it's a KeyFrame bug or perhaps it is intended this way. Btw I saw that syntax on [link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JavaFX/1010__JavaFX_Timeline_Animation.htm)